# Why Photon cannot find the JavaFx library

Tags: java, javafx

I have recently install Eclipse Photon and when trying to compile a desktop project I was working on, Photon cannot find the JavaFx library. All the JavaFx so all the import javafx.xxxx are unresolved. I am just porting from Oxygen to Photon, no changes were made to the code.
Recreating the project using Java 10 does not work either.
What can I do to fix this issue.

Comment: You installed e(fx)clipse yet? Or another FX plugin (can't remember if there are alternative plugins)?

Comment: Not enough detail here I'm afraid - Is it just your specific code that's not working? Can you create a blank project in eclipse using Java 10 and import any JavaFX libraries into that?

Comment: Are you using OracleJDK or OpenJDK?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was missing e(fx)clipse.